# How Ionic constructor works

Tags: constructor, ionic3

I have a problem with ionic constructor. Actually a Java program constructor works line by line. But in my Ionic application I have called a back-end service and getting some data and populate my variables with the received data.

```
constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams, public patientService: PatientServiceProvider, public scanner: BarcodeScanner) {
this.id = this.navParams.get('id');
this.patientService.searchPatientById(this.id).subscribe(res => {
  this.id = res.id;
  this.mobile = res.mobile;
  this.fname = res.firstname;
  this.lname = res.lastName;
  console.log("print this:"+this.mobile);
});  
this.mobile = this.navParams.get('mobile');
console.log(this.id);
console.log("****"+this.mobile);
}
```

In above code my service working fine. My problem is last line execute before the service call. That means my output will look like

5656
"****"+94758968989
print this:undefined

Why this happened. This is not executed line by line.

Comment: you should use Asynchronous call to make it happen.

Answer (score 0):

Your `patientService` returns an Observable, so so functionCall `searchPatientById()` is asyncron. That means that after the Functioncall the next lines will be executed and the part in the `subscribe` is executed when you get a result.

To avoid that, you have more options, for example you can create another method which should be executed AFTER the async call and than call that method at the end in the `subscribe`. Or you can use `async/await` like this:

```
constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams, public 
patientService: PatientServiceProvider, public scanner: BarcodeScanner) {
    this.init();
}

async init() {
  this.id = this.navParams.get('id');
  let res = await this.patientService.searchPatientById(this.id);
  this.id = res.id;
  this.mobile = res.mobile;
  this.fname = res.firstname;
  this.lname = res.lastName;
  console.log("print this:"+this.mobile);
  this.mobile = this.navParams.get('mobile');
  console.log(this.id);
  console.log("****"+this.mobile);
}
```